# How to annotate JMX beans with OSGi native annotations?

Tags: osgi, aem, jmx

I have a JMX bean which is running on felix scr annotations (AEM 6.4.8, Java 8) and would like to refactor it so it uses OSGi annotations instead. Basically, it's pretty clear what to do, there is only one tiny little "=" that I guess needs to be escaped?
The old code looks like this:

```
@Component(immediate=true)
@Property(name="jmx.objectname", value={"com.mypackage.monitoring:type=HierarchyModificationListenerMbean"})
@Service
public class HierarchyModificationListenerMbeanImpl
extends AnnotatedStandardMBean
implements ListenerStats {
```

The refactored code would then be:

```
@Component(immediate=true, service = ListenerStats.class, property = {"jmx.objectname=com.mypackage.monitoring:type=HierarchyModificationListenerMbean"})
public class HierarchyModificationListenerMbeanImpl
extends AnnotatedStandardMBean
implements ListenerStats {
```

I am not sure how to deal with the ":type=" in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this page https://aem.redquark.org/2018/10/day-16-creating-jmx-mbeans-in-aem.html it looks like the property definition you have should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

your code looks good to me. only thing is, do you have an interface `HierarchyModificationListenerMbean`? your implementation class should declare that it implements such interface

Example:

```java
public interface MyMBean {

}
```

```js
@Component(service = DynamicMBean.class, property = {
        "jmx.objectname=com.yourproject.osgi:type=MyMBean"
})
public class MyMBeanImpl extends AnnotatedStandardMBean implements MyMBean {
   public MyMBeanImpl() {
       super(MyMBean.class)
   }
}
```